# How to upgrade version of libpng on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I installed libpng using `apt-get install libpng12-dev` which installed version `libpng 1.2.50`.

I would instead like to install version `libpng 1.6.18`.

How can I install `libpng 1.6.18` on ubuntu?

My Ubuntu version is:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Answer (score 1):

1.6.18 does not exist. Only 1.6.20, 1.6.21 and (beta) 1.6.22 exist on libpng's sourceforge website. 1.6.18 might be a removed beta.

As you apparently do not have the newest versions of libpng in your repository, I recommend compiling libpng yourself. This is how you can do it:

How to compile libpng 1.6.21:

```
$ wget https://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/libpng/libpng16/older-releases/1.6.21/libpng-1.6.21.tar.gz -O libpng.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf libpng.tar.gz
$ cd libpng-1.6.21
$ sudo bash configure --prefix=/usr/local/libpng
$ sudo make install
```

Comment: what is command configure?

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install libpng16-dev

Comment: Based on https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng this specific package (`libpng16-dev`) only exists for Ubuntu Xenial aka 16.04LTS, which is not the OP version.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your distribution online packages explorer (https://packages.ubuntu.com/) and if you search for libpng you get:

- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all
- https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libpng&searchon=names&suite=trusty-updates&section=all

Which show you the only options are `libpng12-0` or `libpng3` which are in fact both `libpng` version `1.2.50-1ubuntu2`

So you can not install any other version of libpng that way, this is because you are using an old version of Ubuntu (was old already in 2016 when you asked your question here), while still supported you should upgrade, especially if you want newer versions of some software (later versions of Ubuntu have libpng version `1.6.20-2`).

Otherwise your 2 other options are:

- find someone somewhere that packaged the version you need for your distribution (or alternatively build yourself such package, you need to understand how your distribution packages are built and you will need to handle all dependencies)
- install the version you need by hand, like @user333044 answered; note that compiling libraries is always more complicated than compiling a software because after compilation the results will be stored in non standard places (it would be an even worse idea to overwrite the standard version installed by packages), and you need to specify that when you will compile other tools needing this library (as a library by itself is of no use if no tool uses it). You may also have solutions with dymanic libraries and linker options but this is complicated too.